# Looping inside of array with objects to get one of it property

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, linked-list

I need a help with JS array task.

I have an **array** that looks like that:

```
const array = [
 {name: 'Show_Everything__c', controllerName: null, value: true},
 {name: 'Vehicle_Type__c', controllerName: 'Show_Everything__c', value: "Car"},
 {name: 'Car__c', controllerName: 'Vehicle_Type__c', value: "BMW"},
 {name: 'Model__c', controllerName: 'Car__c', value: '330i'}
];
```

and I have a **key** that represent one of those objects name.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

if my `key=Vehicle_Type__c`, I want to check if **Vehicle_Type__c** exist somewhere inside an array of objects as a **controllerValue**, if it's exist, than add it to new array, and (based on this example) because **Vehicle_Type__c** exist on an object with name **Car__c**, now I want to check if **Car__c** exist somewhere as a **controllerName**.

So I want to have an array that contains `const newArray = [Car__c, Model__c ]`

I had something like that right now:

```
const dependentField = array.find(field => field.controllerName === key).name;
const dependentField_2 = array.find(field => field.controllerName === dependentField).name;
const dependentField_3 = array.find(field => field.controllerName === dependentField_2).name;
```

But I would like to have something generic, without logic duplication.

Any ideas or examples would be highly appreciated, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to make that search and called it recursively.

### Solution 1

*Simple code, to understand the logic (this solution will modify an initial global variable)*

```
// Your data
const array = [
 {name: 'Show_Everything__c', controllerName: null, value: true},
 {name: 'Vehicle_Type__c', controllerName: 'Show_Everything__c', value: "Car"},
 {name: 'Car__c', controllerName: 'Vehicle_Type__c', value: "BMW"},
 {name: 'Model__c', controllerName: 'Car__c', value: '330i'}
];

// The final array with all founded names
const newArray = [];

// Your recursive function
const findName = (value) => {
    array.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.controllerName === value) {
            // If the key exists, save in the array and make a new search with this key                
            newArray.push(item.name);
            findName(item.name);
        }
    })
}

// Starts the application by calling the fuction with the initial desired value
findName("Vehicle_Type__c");

// Check the results
console.log(newArray);
```

---

### Solution 2

*More complex approach to use immutability principle*

```
// Your data
const array = [
 {name: 'Show_Everything__c', controllerName: null, value: true},
 {name: 'Vehicle_Type__c', controllerName: 'Show_Everything__c', value: "Car"},
 {name: 'Car__c', controllerName: 'Vehicle_Type__c', value: "BMW"},
 {name: 'Model__c', controllerName: 'Car__c', value: '330i'}
];


// Your filter function
const findName = (value) => {
  const filteredData = array.filter(item => item.controllerName === value);
  const filteredName = filteredData.map(item => item.name);
  return filteredName;
}

// Your recursive and immutable function
const findDependencies = (acc, keyValue) => {
    const results = findName(keyValue);
    if (results.length > 0) {
      return results.map((item) => {
        return findDependencies([...acc, ...results], item);
      }).flat();
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
}

// Starts the application by calling the fuction with the initial desired value
const newArray = findDependencies([], "Show_Everything__c");

// Check the results
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: last line logging should be newArray

Comment: findName should define the new array and return it, a function that mutates a global variable is bad design and not reusable.

Comment: Thanks @DDupont, I updated the name to match the original question and forgot that line :)

Comment: I agree with you @AdrianBrand. My original answer intent was just to show the logic. I updated the answer to include an immutable version of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, @BrunoMonteiro.
For some reason solution #2 is not correct. it doesn't add all values to the array, I'm trying to figured out why

Comment: @Ar2zee are you sure? It works fine here: https://playcode.io/380097?tabs=script.js,preview,console

Let me know if you have any errors and I can take a look

Comment: @Ar2zee also, let me know which browser you are using and if you have only the JS code or if you put it inside a bigger application :)

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. you can check it here: playcode.io/380097?tabs=script.js,preview,console if you will change line **26** to `const newArray = findDependencies([], "Show_Everything__c");` the array has only 2 values but suppose to have 3 like that: `[
"Vehicle_Type__c" ,
"Car__c",
"Model__c"
]`

Comment: @Ar2zee my bad! I updated the code in the answer. Also updated the reference link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196681/discussion-between-ar2zee-and-bruno-monteiro).

Comment: I have updated my solution to be recursive and much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array into the ones that are in the params list spread into an array and recursively call it with the new names until there are no more.

```js
const array = [
 {name: 'Show_Everything__c', controllerName: null, value: true},
 {name: 'Vehicle_Type__c', controllerName: 'Show_Everything__c', value: "Car"},
 {name: 'Car__c', controllerName: 'Vehicle_Type__c', value: "BMW"},
 {name: 'Model__c', controllerName: 'Car__c', value: '330i'}
];

const controllerNames = (array, ...controllers) => {
  const names = array.reduce((names, item) => controllers.some(c => item.controllerName === c) ? [...names, item.name] : names, []);
  return names.length ? [...names, ...controllerNames(array, ...names)] : names;
};

console.log(controllerNames(array, 'Vehicle_Type__c'));
```

array is the first paramaters and the ... spread operator collects the rest of the paramaters into an array. Reduce looks if the current controllerName is in the controllers array and returns a new array with it's name or return the existing names. [] is the starting accumulator of an empty name array.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I was going to update my answer to point to yours as the immutable option, however, your answer doesn't solve the problem. OP wants to search for "Vehicle_Type__c" only, and find the dependencies without manually adding a second parameter (e.g.: "Car__c"), which is not very scalable :)

Comment: Ok, I made it recursive to add the next level until the list of names is empty.